# reverseArrayInPlace eloquentJS

Tags: javascript

I figured out a simple way to solve this, and it worked out.

```
var reverseArrayInPlace = function(arr) {
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result.unshift(arr[i]);
  }
  for(var j = 0; j < result.length; j ++) {
    arr[j] = result[j];
  }
};
//test
var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
//[5,4,3,2,1]
```

However, i'm wonder why can't I use an even simpler way by just assign the `arr` argument to the result value which is [5,4,3,2,1]? But the code below doesn't work, it still prints out `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

```
var reverseArrayInPlace = function(arr) {
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result.unshift(arr[i]);
  }
  arr = result;
};
//test
var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
//[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding how references work. Setting `arr = result;` inside your fn modifies your local reference, not `arrayValue`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your dev console:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];

function retArr(arr){
    var res = arr;
    res = [3,2,1];
    return res;
}
retArr(arr); // returns 3,2,1
console.log(arr); // logs 1,2,3
```

All you did was create a new array!
Parameters of functions are pass-by-value.
the reason direct for-loop access works is because array properties are pass-by-reference.

P.S. an actual in-place reversal would look like this:

```
function reverseInPlace(array){
    var swap = function(i,j){
        var t = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = t;
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length/2;i++){
        swap(i,array.length-i-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.slice()`, `.pop()`

```js
var reverseArrayInPlace = function(arr) {
  var copy = arr.slice(0);
  for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++) {
    arr[n] = copy.pop();
  }
  return arr
};
//test
var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
```

Alternatively, using `Array.prototype.sort()`

```js
var reverseArrayInPlace = function(arr) {
  arr.sort(function(a, b, index) {
    return index < index + 1 ? -1 : 1
  });
};
//test
var arrayValue = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
```

Comment: Your sorting one would not work because it would only work on numbers.

Comment: But I was surprised that it actually worked on numbers. Never knew about the index parameter. Even so, The sort one would be slower compared to an in-place reversal algorithm. Some browsers use different algorithms as well. How would you know it would work on all browsers?

Comment: _"How would you know it would work on all browsers?"_ Try at all browsers ?

Comment: I just did test it. it doesn't work on strings. on chrome nor on firefox, only for numbers it seems.

Comment: wait, change `return index < index+1 ? b:a` to `return index < index+1? -1:1;`

Comment: I actually never new you could reverse using `Array.prototype.sort` so +1

Comment: After messing around with the `sort` reversal algorithm, I realized that I may NEVER want to EVER use it again. The runtime in chrome is horrid compared to actual inplace reversal algorithms.